# Such Business vs Such a Business? Which one is correct?

Tags: countability

Singular nouns use an indefinite article (managing a business) and plural nouns use a definite article or no article (Managing the businesses or Managing businesses.)

I have heard (not sure if read) the expression "Running such business". Is that grammatically correct? Or should I write "Running such a business"? Or are both correct?

Comment: I don't know where you found that 'rule'. You should use a definite article when referring to one or more particular businesses. You can say _Running such a business_ to mean 'a business of the kind I have been talking about'.

Comment: This answers the question. Can you redact your comment as an answer, so I can close it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'rule' that you mention doesn't exist.

You should use the indefinite article when referring to an unspecified business, the definite article for one or more particular businesses.

You can say *Running such **a** business* to mean 'a business of the kind I have been talking about'.